# show array size with will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to return the total number of results from this query:

```
@users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)
```

`@users.size` simply gives me the number of results on a page. If page 1 has 2 users, then `@users.size` will be 2. If page 2 has 1 user, then `@users.size` will be 1.

How can I show the size of all the users?

Answer (score 8):

will_paginate adds some attributes to the returned collection one of them is `total_entries` which is the total number of results the query would have returned.

Answer (score -3):

You need to call another Active Record model, named [count](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#calculations) as such:

```
@count = User.count
```

Comment: The plugin performs the `count` operation and sets the count to `total_entries` attribute. There is no need to do a second count.